# How to Fix Nodejs Heroku Running into Error?

Tags: heroku

I followed the step to upload my backend to Heroku from this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rSkxia0ZZQ0, and I got this error:

```
Enumerating objects: 15, done.
Counting objects: 100% (15/15), done.
Delta compression using up to 16 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (10/10), done.
Writing objects: 100% (10/10), 3.14 KiB | 1.57 MiB/s, done.
Total 10 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Using buildpacks:
remote:        1. https://github.com/timanovsky/subdir-heroku-buildpack.git
remote:        2. heroku/nodejs
remote: -----> Subdir buildpack app detected
remote: PROJECT_PATH is undefined
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Subdir buildpack app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: aad8206689cb2d86d27ef0e2a124aa9701bf8a7b
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version aad8206689cb2d86d27ef0e2a124aa9701bf8a7b
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to heroku-skiplagged-final.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/heroku-skiplagged-final.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/heroku-skiplagged-final.git'
```

Procfile:

```
web: node backend/backend.js
```

[Picture of my Folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7hW5d.png)

[Procfile Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g1UPC.png)

[Package.json Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOteg.png)

[PROJECT_PATH and BuildPacks from Heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCxAF.png)

Video Link with the error above: https://youtu.be/T6eWAdPVOJI

Answer (score 0):

Heroku sees that you made some changes in your visual studio code or what are you using and it's telling you that you didn't push on git the last version of your app.

> remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been
> built: aad8206689cb2d86d27ef0e2a124aa9701bf8a7b remote:  ! remote:  !
> We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with
> version aad8206689cb2d86d27ef0e2a124aa9701bf8a7b

You need to commit your changes in the project and push them to git and after you can push the git on the heroku server.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How do you do commit your changes? Is it like this from Heroku website:  "git commit -am "[Name of commit] "?                                                                               How do you push the git on the heroku server? Is it: "git push heroku master"? May I ask you to be more specific cause I don't know what you mean by that? I've tried these two commands 20 times already and I got the above error.

Comment: I've recorded my steps right here. Video Link: https://youtu.be/T6eWAdPVOJI.

Comment: If you don't mind, may I ask you if there's anyway I ask you to review my Heroku uploading process live like via Zoom or some other services.?

Comment: After you use git commit you need to use git push origin master. And after that heroku create -a AppName and after git push heroku master.

Comment: Ok, I did that and I got this error here: https://pastecode.io/s/pat281s0.

Comment: I really suggest that a good idea to diagnose the problem is to see things live and see how to solve it on the spot rather than posting back and forth. Not like it's a privacy issue, but it really expedites troubleshooting process.

Comment: The ting is I'm not an expert on heroku, I've run in the same problem and at me was the code differences between  VS code and git. at node JS I know very little. Now it's seems that you have errors in your app, it can not be build by server. on local is running fine? without errors? Let's try on discord you can find me with Diablo#2836

Comment: I've sent you a friend request.

Comment: Heroku doesn't see _anything_ on your local machine. This message just means you aren't pushing any new commits.